how to change the react-circular-progressbar color
I want to change the circular color, I try to look for the other solution but is not working  to me anyone who  knows or ideas how to change this color ?
<CircularProgressbar value={skill.percentage} text={${skill.percentage}%}/>

The documentation of react-circular-progressbar is very robust. I suggest you to check it out! There is a instructions how to apply styles to the progressbar.

thank you, it is just a path, and set the stroke value to any color
